# Proof of transformation of Hypergeometric to Whittaker.

Tags: limits, asymptotics, approximation, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am working on [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491687900984), regarding the spectrum of a certain operator in the hyperbolic plane, and at a certain point are presented with an hypergeometric function
\begin{equation}
\text{}_2 F_1\left(t-b, t-b;2t;\frac{1}{1-\sigma}\right)
\end{equation}
which they explore in a large limit of a variable $a \to \infty$ that, to leading order, leads to the approximations
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1-\sigma} \sim- \frac{r^2}{4a^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 t \sim Ba^2 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2E}{B}
\end{equation}
and then they state that in this limit the hypergeometric function goes to the Whittaker function(equation 5.10)
\begin{equation}
 \text{}_2F_1\left(t-b, t-b;2t; \frac{1}{1-\sigma} \right) \sim \rho ^{-2E/B} e^{\rho/2} \,W_{2E/B, 0}(\rho) 
\end{equation}
where $b = Ba^2$ and $\rho = Br^2/2$.

I'm having trouble demonstrating that we get this relation between these 2 functions in the limit $a\to \infty$.